# Where do Azure Queue Storage Messages go?

Tags: azure-functions, messaging, azure-storage-queues

I'm just learning about Queue Storage Message-triggered Azure Functions. I'm able to generate a message and trigger the Function, but where do the messages go once the Function ack's them?

They just disappear from the Queue.

- What if I want to reprocess them?
- How is this accomplished?

Ideally I want to tell the Queue when to "dequeue" the message rather than it being automatically handled somehow.

Comment: If you have a consumer on the queue, it will automatically dequeue the messages once it's published to it. i.e. it will consume it for processing (or whatever the consumer does with it)

Comment: Is there any way to stop automatic dequeue'ing? The message is removed from the queue even if the consumer fails downstream. I want to persist the message until processing is verified complete, then send a dequeue signal to the storage queue.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm able to generate a message and trigger the Function, but where do
> the messages go once the Function ack's them?

A message is dequeued from the queue when the Function is invoked. As part of the dequeuing process, the message becomes invisible for a certain amount of time (specified via visibility timeout duration). This is needed so that only one consumer processes a message at any given point of time.

If the Function is able to process the message successfully, it will be automatically deleted. You can't really control that behavior.

If the Function is not able to process the message, the message will reappear in the queue after it's visibility timeout duration expires and will be picked up again by another instance of Function.

Once a message has been retried "n" number of times and the result has always been unsuccessful, Function puts the message in a deadletter/poison queue that I believe will have the the name like `<yourqueuename>-poison`.

Comment: @GuaravMantri, when you say `If the Function is able to process the message successfully, it will be automatically deleted.`, what constitutes "processing the message successfully"? If the Function *acknowledges/accepts/takes* the message it seems the message is then deleted. But if the Function fails after this (Status 500, etc.) OR if a downstream process fails, the message is gone forever. How do we persist the message until a certain point in the process? Ex: After blob has been fully processed, dequeue message.

Comment: `If the Function acknowledges/accepts/takes the message it seems the message is then deleted` - That should not be the case. The message is deleted only when the Function completes its processing successfully. If the Function throws an exception, the message is enqueued again.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification. I'll have to find a way to view this in App Insights/Log Analytics. One more example: Lets say the Function throws no exception, but a process further downstream fails and the Queue Message needs to be enqueued again. Is there a pattern for persisting queue messages for replay later?

Comment: `Lets say the Function throws no exception, but a process further downstream fails and the Queue Message needs to be enqueued again. Is there a pattern for persisting queue messages for replay later?` - I am not sure I understand. May I recommend updating your question and provide all the necessary details or ask a new question with all these details. IMHO, comments is not the right place to discuss these.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593623/is-there-a-pattern-for-replaying-azure-queue-storage-messages

Answer (score 0):

`Azure Storage Queues` have a `Delivery Guarantee` of `At least once` , meaning once you receive a message it'll be dequeued and becomes invisible for `visibilitytimeout` duration which has a default value of `30 seconds`. It will not be automatically deleted and you'll need to explicitly delete the messages from your `Azure Storage Queue`  otherwise they'll show up again in the queue after the `visibilitytimeout` . Here is some useful links

Storage Queue Introduction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction

Get Messages Operation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages

Storage Queue vs. Service Bus Queue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted