# Is there a pattern for replaying Azure Queue Storage messages?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-storage-queues

I'm looking for a method of re-enqueueing messages if failures happen downstream after a message has been processed. Is there a pattern for this that I can study?

**Example:**

- EventGrid event is triggered when a blob is uploaded to storage account
- Queue Storage is subscribed to the event
- Azure Function is triggered by Queue Storage
- Function processes the message

  - Parses a BlobURL from EventGrid message
  - Manipulates blob
  - Successfully completes
- SOME KIND OF ISSUE HAPPENS downstream from here and Function needs to reprocess the Queue Storage message

**How can I persist the Queue Message until all downstream processes have completed?**

Comment: `SOME KIND OF ISSUE HAPPENS downstream` - Can you describe that? Does this happen after the Function has completed its processing (i.e. outside of Function)?

Comment: Yes, after the Function has completed its processing. Example: Manipulated blob is corrupt or a Logic App that handles it further fails.

Comment: @ericOnline just a thought, if the LogicApp fails then you should handle it there.  If a blob is corrupted then that's a different story.  Hard to solve, BUT, you could also persist your message in a storage container or something and reprocess it after a period if it still remains.  In your downstream processes, delete the blob at the end when everything is successful.  It won't be re-triggered if you delete it prior to the reprocessing job execution.  That would indicate that it didn't fail further downstream.  Orchestration sounds like the key here.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing using Table Storage.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation. Sometimes the message can't be processed yet because a requirement hasn't been met. I started by creating a RetryableMessage.

```
public class RetryableMessage<T>
{
    // number of times we try to send the message before giving up
    public int TriesRemaining = 15;
    public T Message { get; set; }
}
```

I put the actual message in the Message field, then, if the message processing doesn't go well, but maybe it would go well if I tried it again I do something like this

```
if (shouldRetry)
{
    queuedMessage.TriesRemaining--;
    if (queuedMessage.TriesRemaining > 0)
    {
        queue.Add(queuedMessage);
    }
}
```

That just adds it back to the end of the queue so I can try again. I included a max number of tries so if it never ends up working it stops requeuing it.

This works for my situation because it's usually processing a lot of messages and one of the others will make this one will work.  If you only have one message at a time and it just doesn't work, this pattern isn't for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `Azure Storage Queue` , the messages will have a `Delivery Guarantee` of `At least once`, which means once you receive them, they'll be hidden for `visibilitytimeout` duration (default to 30 seconds ) and show up in the queue afterwards.
You'll have to explicitly delete them once you're done with each message, so you can postpone the deleting part after you're done with all your downstream operations. or if any of those operations fail the message will be automatically available after its visibilitytimeout finishes.

As it says in [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted) , using azure storage queue is one of the ways of bypassing the problem you're having :

```
Your application wants to track progress for processing a message in the queue. It's useful if the worker processing a message crashes. Another worker can then use that information to continue from where the prior worker left off.
```